# I need help understanding how to use a javascript function in an onclick event in a php file

Tags: javascript, php, function

I created a javascript file, made a function, and then linked my html file with it in the head. It worked. When I copy and pasted the exact same thing into a php file, the function suddenly doesn't work. I need a way to make the function work in the php file.

This is the javascript function:

```
function showField(){
    if(document.getElementById("downtown").checked && document.getElementById("pricerange").value == "100"){
        document.getElementById("newField").removeAttribute("hidden");
    }
}
```

This is the php where i try to call the function:

```php
<input type="button" name = "search" value="Search" id="search" onclick="showField();">
```

This is in my head where I linked the javascript file:

```php
<script src = "a3q5.js"></script>
```

Comment: because your php has no idea what showField() is on the server side

Comment: do you get an error in the console? If so, what does it say?

Comment: No errors, it simply doesn't do the onclick event. I'm pretty sure it's because php doesn't recognize that it's a JS function and not a php one. I just need a way to let it know.

Comment: not really, are you serving the PHP to a browser? the browser is the one that executes your JavaScript (i.e. simply opening the file in the browser might not work)

Comment: in your HTML, do you have an element with `id='downtown'` and another one for `pricerange` and `newField` ? (I am assuming yes, since you said it worked before but asking just in case)

Comment: I have all those ids yeah. And im running my php through a server.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that I don't know what the rest of your code is, I would just make sure you have the normal HTML stuff:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" name = "search" value="Search" id="search" onclick="showField();"> 
        <script src = "a3q5.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be here, Put this to your PHP. It worked for me

```
<?php

// your code

echo '<script src = "a3q5.js"></script>';

// your code

?>
```